C# summary a class ,and have the docs in the instance
I'm still learning C# and I don't know if it's possible but if I summary a class, I want this comment to show when I instantiate it in another class.
I want to do this:
/// <summary>
/// This is my class
/// </summary>
class MyClass {}

// in the main for examples
class Program
{
    // And I want the comments I write shown here when I hover it
    MyClass m = new MyClass()
}

Is it possible guys?

Doesn't it already show up when you hover MyClass? Even if you use var, when you hover var, it still shows up the correct class and its summary.

Yea, this works by default (and is the main purpose of this cool feature). There might however be some option to disable it.

Yeah it work when I hover it in the MyClass class but not in the program

Yes, it works in the program when you hover over the MyClass that is in MyClass m.
